# Ceiling speakers central switch

Tags: speakers, signal-processing

I have **16** 2-way **ceiling speakers** (2-way speaker, RMS: 30W, Max: 60W, 8 Ohm
(coax, polypropylen membrane)) and I would like to have a box, to which I could connect them all and 1 (maybe more) input interface. So the audio signal would be transported to all of them. (Your whole house is playing music.). Additionaly, I would appreciate a possibility to switch some zones on/off. Third, it would be good if I could control the box remotely. The flat is not big though.. only about 80m^2

I have no idea how it is called and if it is possible. Any idea? Thank you very much

These are my speakers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Universal Remote Control, Speakercraft, Niles, Savant, Control4, Crestron and AMX all make great products for distributed whole house audio (and video). They are listed in general order of least expensive to most expensive. Least expensive does not mean low quality.

These companies all have solution such as multi-room amplifiers (that can share sources or have their own dedicated sources) and slick ways to control and interface with A LOT of other products. Each system has the ability to control almost every aspect of your home with the right equipment.

I would contact a "Custom Integration" specialist to cause the least mount of stress.

Answer (score 0):

You need a central processor/head unit. Which one depends on the type of speakers and size of your rooms. I am assuming this is a commercial space?

Past a certain distance between speakers, it becomes impractical to use a simple head unit and you will need to use multiple smaller units. Your best bet is to go to a local a/v supply and ask them. If you tell me where you are geographically I may be able to suggest somebody.

Comment: I edited the answer, thank you. The distances between them are not very big, We are talking about 2 meters

Comment: That picture is not too useful. We need at least wattage, referably make & model. Are they in separate rooms? Do you need the same signal to all 16 speakers? Odds are you will need one head unit and multiple amps (4-8)

Comment: yes, there are: 1 room with 4 speakers, the rest with 2 speakers.

Comment: again, make/model and power in watts please

Comment: 2-way speaker, RMS: 30W, Max: 60W, 8 Ohm
(coax, polypropylen membrane)

Answer (score 0):

As far as wiring, you generally want to run them in series in loops for each zone.  You then need a head unit that supports however many zones, though you can also use variable resistors to branch off multiple circuits from one feed with differing volumes, but the same signal going to each, but you still need separate circuits for each zone that are wired together at the volume controls (or the head unit if you want different outputs for each.)

Depending on the power needed, you may be able to use a simple head unit, but the best quality will result from matching the power output and resistance of the speakers to the head unit you use.  In a pinch, I've run over 20 speakers in 3 zones off of one receiver and amplifier with decent enough quality, but it depends on the speakers and your quality needs.

Comment: Well the quality does not have to be very good, i would be satisfied with mediocre... And yes I want the same signal in all of them, being able to change volume and turn them on or off. Nothing else.

Comment: Anyways, I need a receiver and many amplifiers, right? With the mediocre quality in mind, is there any device capable of that?

Comment: You should be able to run multiple speakers in series as long as you have sufficient power.  In ceiling speakers are generally particularly designed for this, though it's probably best to look at the installation instructions for the particular speakers you have.  If this is the case, you can run everything off of one amplifier and receiver as long as you want them to all have the same thing playing.  If you want multiple things playing, you'll need either a receiver and amp per zone or a receiver that supports multiple zones.

Comment: Maybe use remotely controlled electrical relays to switch audio signal on/off to zones - the relay contacts have to be good though. Just an idea. You can get cheap radio modules (like $2 each) but using them requires some electronic knowledge.

Comment: @Andyaka - good point.  My only experience with systems like this was putting a system that they did a hack job on the way to closing a dentists office when we took over the building.  I spent months piecing the system together from what was in place because it was a non-profit that didn't have a budget to make the system work.  We actually ended up building our own controller, but I forget what circuitry exactly we put in to it.  It wasn't remote controllable though.